# How to get selected value from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a problem with getting out the selected value in my `DropDownList`. 
In my `ViewModel` I created a list

```
public SelectList movies;
```

and populated it in GET method with the following values

```
foreach (Movies m in db.Movies)
{
     movies.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m.Title, Value = m.IdMovies.ToString() });
}
```

And displayed it like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdMovies, Model.movies, "--Select Movie--")`
```

How can I get the selected value in my `POST` method?

Comment: Please describe your POST method in controller and what data you send?

Comment: As soon as you selects a text the associated value automatically gets assigned to `IdMovies` property. Make sure the form method is post and the whole model is passed on to controller as arguement, Thats it.